# In Domain Driven Design the factory classes can access to infraestructure?

Tags: domain-driven-design, factory

If necessary, a factory can access elements of the infrastructure to build an object?. In a particular case, I have an object that I need to add email signature that is stored as a parameter in the configuration layer of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DDD, a Factory is at the same architectural level as a Repository, but for creating new objects instead of loading existing objects. So it can call infrastructure services just like the repository.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one correct answer to this problem. If the factory itself is part of your application layer this should be fine. You can also add an application service that hands the email signature down into your domain when needed.

Comment: In DDD definitions, Repository and Factory are part of the Domain Layer, not the application layer. See e.g. http://evan.bottch.com/2007/12/06/factory-and-repository-in-the-domain/